# Remove account in Windows8 Mail App without having the password

Tags: windows-8, email, windows-8-mail-app

So here's the thing: I have previously added my work mail account onto my Windows Surface but have since switched jobs. Just yesterday I bought a new laptop and logged on with my Windows account - it immediately loaded all my mail accounts into the mail app. But since my previous boss switched my passwords, I cannot get the mailbox out of the app. Any help on that?

Comment: Have you called up your old boss and explained the situation to him?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the Mail app closed completely (dragging it down until it rotates to its splash screen at the bottom of the screen and drag further).
2. Set the Surface in "Airplane Mode" via the Settings Charm and the WiFi symbol
3. Open the Mail app and go to the Account Settings pane.
4. Touch the Corp. Account and scroll to the bottom of the following screen.
5. Click the "Remove Account" button and confirm to Remove it From All Devices.